# Aiming grenade throws

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I keep blowing myself up and it's starting to get old.

Is it possible to aim my grenade throws or at least find out roughly how far away the grenade's going to land?

Comment: Have you tried throwing grenades from cover? That makes it pretty easy to not blow yourself up, simply because the grenade is around the corner from you.

Comment: @Raven I did... the grenade got stuck in the box that was on top of the boxes I was hiding behind. It wasn't pretty. :)

Comment: Boxes 1, Jenson 0. Solid Snake take note.

Comment: @Raven, that score depends on how many boxes she's hurled to their death.

Comment: I wish I could answer this, but grenade throws are just plain odd in DE:HR. They never really go where you expect. You get used to it after a few throws (as long as they actually go far enough away to not blow you up :P).

Comment: I always found they tended to land right about where the reticle was when I threw them

Comment: I got used to throwing grenades after a while, after 1 or 2 deaths, I just stopped having problems with it. It's hard to describe; it's this feeling of where it'd generally end up....

Comment: You never asked for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is sadly no way to accurately throw a grenade. Not like other games where they show you the path the grenade will take. You can guesstimate where it will land, but that's about it.

On several occasion I ended up throwing a grenade from cover just to have it land at my feet while I ran away with my arms in the air. Figuratively speaking :)